# Cannot generate JPA Hibernate Metamodel classes in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, intellij-idea, maven-dependency

In my Java project, I get "*java: cannot find symbol*" errors pointing Metamodel classes e.g. `Company_`.

So, first I checked `my-project\target\generated-sources\annotations` and see that it is empty. Then, after several search on the web and SO, I see that the necessary settings seems to be ok and this is the first time I get this problem.

Here is corresponding settings in `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

And I have already had this settings and these have not been changed:

[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYVes.png)

> Settings > Build execution, Deployment > Compiler > Annotation Processors > my-project (selected) : 
> Enable annotation processing (checked)
> Obtain processors from project classpath (selected)
> Store generated sources relative to: Module content root
> Production sources directory: target\generated-sources\annotations
> Test sources directory: target\generated-test-sources\test-annotations

I tried to rebuild project, module, etc. but there is still nothing in `my-project\target\generated-sources\annotations` directory. So, how can I generate these **JPA Hibernate Metamodel classes** in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: Does anybody else have ever used `JPA Hibernate Metamodel classes in IntelliJ IDEA`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try remove .Final from version or just use another version

Comment: I tried `<version>5.5.6</version>` and Rebuild project after Reloading all Maven project. But still the same problem. Is there any step that I should apply e.g. Invalidating caches?

Comment: Sometimes refresh maven dependency and rebuild project help.

Comment: Do you mean clicking "Reload all Maven projects" button? I did it, and already Rebuild project. It is really too strange.

Comment: "Do you mean clicking "Reload all Maven projects" button? "
yes. As I remember all time when I had similar situation I've just changed version of dependency. Unfortunately I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: Switching to another branch and then rebuilding + reloading all maven dependency **SEEMS TO** solve the problem, but when I debug the app, it throws the same errors again :(

Comment: Finally I fixed the problem by deleting and re-creating the branch that has problem. Thanks a lot for your helps.